# PHP mail form with multiple recipients & different contents: Sometimes not received

Tags: php, forms, webforms

I want to send an online email form to two addresses.
The content of the mail should be different for each recipient.
One mail for further processing (with password) and the another mail as personal copy (without password).

The problem:

The web form I created works basically, but **some users reported that they didn't get a personal copy.**  <strike>I couldn't reproduce the bug yet.</strike> (See update below) I now have the apprehension that sometimes it doesn't send emails to the other address either.
I think it has something to do with the mail processing logic (process.php) ...

How can I avoid this strange behavior? Did I make a coding mistake? Are there any fixes to be done?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Here is the example code:

```
<?php
$to =  $_POST['email'];
$to2 =  'mail@example.com';
$from = $_POST['email'];
$subject = 'Webform for' . $_POST['firstname'] . ' ' . $_POST['lastname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$firstname = $_POST['firstname']; 
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];

$headers   = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8";
$headers[] = "From: {$email}";
$headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();

$message1 = "
Hello $firstname $lastname, \n
here is your personal copy of the web form: \n
Name:       $firstname $lastname
Comment:    $comment \n
Bye, Admin";

$message2 = "
Name:       $firstname $lastname
Password:   $password
Comment:    $comment";

$success = mail($to, $subject, $message1,implode("\r\n",$headers), '-fmail@example.com');       // Personal copy
$success = mail($to2, $subject, $message2,implode("\r\n",$headers), '-fmail@example.com');  // Further processing

if ($success){
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=form.php#success\">";
}
?>
```

---

**UPDATE** [11-24-2015]: I reproduced the bug once (happens very rarely). 
The missing email is not filtered as spam, nor is it appearing anywhere else.
No solution found yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems fine.

The email is maybe blocked by some providers who consider it spam.

It's not so easy to correctly send an email...

Comment: Now I can rule out that the emails end up in spam folder. I have no solution found yet. Thanks alot for your ideas and help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `logger`, that log the emails addresses which have been successfully mailed.

You can either create a text file and write all the email address on the success from `mail` or use one database table to update the same.

```
$success = mail($to2, $subject, $message2,implode("\r\n",$headers), '-fmail@example.com');

if ($success) {
    // <write the email address to a file OR update to database>
    print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=form.php#success\">";
}
```

---

Also, you're assigning `$success` twice. Fix you code to something like below.

```
$success1 = mail($to, $subject, $message1,implode("\r\n",$headers), '-fmail@example.com');       // Personal copy
$success2 = mail($to2, $subject, $message2,implode("\r\n",$headers), '-fmail@example.com');  // Further processing

if ($success1 && $success2){
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=form.php#success\">";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply!
I changed the code to the nicer: `if ($success1 && $success2){`. 
It still works. But I don't know if it affected the problem yet.

Comment: In this case, either the mails are going to spam or the email provider is blocking the emails.

Comment: I reproduced the bug once (It strangely happens very rarely). The missing email is not filtered as spam, nor is it appearing anywhere else. No solution found yet. But thank you for your thoughts so far.